# Is there a simple way to AES-256 GCM decrypt in C, without any external libraries outside of Windows?

Tags: c, aes-gcm

Is it possible to **AES-256 GCM** decrypt in **C**, **without any external libraries outside of Windows**?

I was trying to look for such POC function that would use for example crypt32.dll, but without success.

It doesn't have to be the Windows encryption API, but something else, as long as it's pre-installed.

Also a example function and links, would be much appreciated.

**Edit:**
I've tried to craft a working decrypt function using bcrypt.h as suggested below, but without success:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <bcrypt.h>

NTSTATUS decrypt_AES_GCM(const BYTE *encryptedData, ULONG encryptedDataLength,
                         const BYTE *aad, ULONG aadLength,
                         const BYTE *iv, ULONG ivLength,
                         const BYTE *authTag, ULONG authTagLength,
                         const BYTE *key, ULONG keyLength,
                         BYTE *decryptedData, ULONG decryptedDataLength);

int main() {
    // Hardcoded data
    BYTE iv[] = {0x10, 0x8d, 0x92, 0x57, 0x99, 0x1d, 0x95, 0x2d, 0xa1, 0xa3, 0xed, 0xc6};
    BYTE ciphertext[] = {0x7e, 0xea, 0xfe, 0x7d, 0xd6, 0xb7, 0xa7, 0x4d, 0xb2, 0x18, 0x73, 0x67, 0x96, 0x93, ..., 0x80, 0x96};
    BYTE secret_key[] = {0x52, 0x99, 0x17, 0xbd, 0xd5, 0xa1, 0xb9, 0x1f, ..., 0x74, 0x74, 0x1a, 0xe1, 0x87, 0x1b, 0x60, 0x07, 0x02, 0xc6, 0x45, 0xea, 0x17, 0x14};
    BYTE aad[] = {};
    BYTE authTag[] = {};
    BYTE decryptedData[100];
    ULONG decryptedDataLength = sizeof(decryptedData);
    NTSTATUS status = decrypt_AES_GCM(ciphertext, 12,
                                      aad, 0,
                                      iv, 12,
                                      authTag, 0,
                                      secret_key, 32,
                                      decryptedData, decryptedDataLength);

    if (BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        printf("Decryption successful.\n");
    } else {
        printf("Decryption failed with status: %08x\n", status);
    }

    return 0;
}


NTSTATUS decrypt_AES_GCM(const BYTE *encryptedData, ULONG encryptedDataLength,
                         const BYTE *aad, ULONG aadLength,
                         const BYTE *iv, ULONG ivLength,
                         const BYTE *authTag, ULONG authTagLength,
                         const BYTE *key, ULONG keyLength,
                         BYTE *decryptedData, ULONG decryptedDataLength) {
    NTSTATUS status = 0;
    DWORD bytesDone = 0;

    BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE algHandle = 0;
    status = BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(&algHandle, BCRYPT_AES_ALGORITHM, NULL, 0);
    if (!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        return status;
    }

    status = BCryptSetProperty(algHandle, BCRYPT_CHAINING_MODE, (PBYTE)BCRYPT_CHAIN_MODE_GCM, sizeof(BCRYPT_CHAIN_MODE_GCM), 0);
    if (!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(algHandle, 0);
        return status;
    }

    BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE keyHandle = 0;
    status = BCryptGenerateSymmetricKey(algHandle, &keyHandle, NULL, 0, (PUCHAR)key, keyLength, 0);
    if (!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(algHandle, 0);
        return status;
    }

    BCRYPT_AUTHENTICATED_CIPHER_MODE_INFO authInfo;
    memset(&authInfo, 0, sizeof(authInfo));
    authInfo.pbNonce = (PUCHAR)iv;
    authInfo.cbNonce = ivLength;
    authInfo.pbTag = (PUCHAR)authTag;
    authInfo.cbTag = authTagLength;
    authInfo.pbAuthData = (PUCHAR)aad;
    authInfo.cbAuthData = aadLength;

    status = BCryptDecrypt(keyHandle, (PUCHAR)encryptedData, encryptedDataLength, &authInfo, NULL, 0, decryptedData, decryptedDataLength, &bytesDone, 0);
    
    BCryptDestroyKey(keyHandle);
    BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(algHandle, 0);

    return status;
}
```

I keep getting error code c000000d:

```
0xC000000D

STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER

An invalid parameter was passed to a service or function.
```

The hard-coded values are straight from a Python code that uses AES-256 GCM, printed like as hex, then converted to byte arrays.

Reference: [How to chain BCryptEncrypt and BCryptDecrypt calls using AES in GCM mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720414/how-to-chain-bcryptencrypt-and-bcryptdecrypt-calls-using-aes-in-gcm-mode)

**Edit 2:**
I've got the code working, thanks to the notices from @Topaco in the comments. The authentication tag, IV and the Encrypted Data, had all been added to the same ciphertext, so took tag from last 16 bytes (auth tag), which had not been done in the Python version of the script. Also replaced `memset(&authInfo, 0, sizeof(authInfo));` with `BCRYPT_INIT_AUTH_MODE_INFO(authInfo);`.

There is only a little issue left. **The output length is over the actual length, meaning when I print the output, it has a few extra bytes**.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <bcrypt.h>

#define NT_SUCCESS(Status)          (((NTSTATUS)(Status)) >= 0)

NTSTATUS decrypt_AES_GCM(const BYTE *encryptedData, ULONG encryptedDataLength,
                         const BYTE *aad, ULONG aadLength,
                         const BYTE *iv, ULONG ivLength,
                         const BYTE *authTag, ULONG authTagLength,
                         const BYTE *key, ULONG keyLength,
                         BYTE *decryptedData, ULONG decryptedDataLength);

int main() {
    // Hardcoded data
    BYTE iv[] = { 0x10, 0x8d, 0x92, 0x57, 0x99, 0x1d, 0x95, 0x2d, 0xa1, 0xa3, 0xed, 0xc6 };
    BYTE ciphertext[] = { 0x7e, 0xea, ..., 0xb7, 0xa7, 0x4d, 0xb2, 0x18, 0x73, 0x67 };
    BYTE secret_key[] = {0x52, 0x99, 0x17, 0xbd, 0xd5, 0xa1, 0xb9, 0x1f, 0xa0, ..., 0x7b, 0x74, 0x74, 0x1a, 0xe1, 0x87, 0x1b, 0x60, 0x07, 0x02, 0xc6, 0x45, 0xea, 0x17, 0x14};
    BYTE aad[] = {  };
    BYTE authTag[16] = { 0x96, 0x93, 0x87, 0x96, 0x7f, 0x14, 0x49, 0x95, 0xaf, 0x3b, 0x9c, 0xb8, 0x80, 0x29, 0x80, 0x96 };
    BYTE decryptedData[100];
    ULONG decryptedDataLength = sizeof(decryptedData);
    NTSTATUS status = decrypt_AES_GCM(ciphertext, sizeof(ciphertext),
                                      aad, 0,
                                      iv, sizeof(iv),
                                      authTag, sizeof(authTag),
                                      secret_key, sizeof(secret_key),
                                      decryptedData, decryptedDataLength);

    if (NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        printf("Decryption successful.\n");
        printf("Decrypted Data (length = %i): %s", decryptedDataLength, decryptedData);
    } else {
        printf("Decryption failed with status: %08x\n", status);
    }

    return 0;
}

NTSTATUS decrypt_AES_GCM(const BYTE *encryptedData, ULONG encryptedDataLength,
                         const BYTE *aad, ULONG aadLength,
                         const BYTE *iv, ULONG ivLength,
                         const BYTE *authTag, ULONG authTagLength,
                         const BYTE *key, ULONG keyLength,
                         BYTE *decryptedData, ULONG decryptedDataLength) {
    NTSTATUS status = 0;
    DWORD bytesDone = 0;

    BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE algHandle = 0;
    status = BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(&algHandle, BCRYPT_AES_ALGORITHM, NULL, 0);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        return status;
    }

    status = BCryptSetProperty(algHandle, BCRYPT_CHAINING_MODE, (PBYTE)BCRYPT_CHAIN_MODE_GCM, sizeof(BCRYPT_CHAIN_MODE_GCM), 0);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(algHandle, 0);
        return status;
    }

    BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE keyHandle = 0;
    status = BCryptGenerateSymmetricKey(algHandle, &keyHandle, NULL, 0, (PUCHAR)key, keyLength, 0);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(algHandle, 0);
        return status;
    }

    BCRYPT_AUTHENTICATED_CIPHER_MODE_INFO authInfo;
    BCRYPT_INIT_AUTH_MODE_INFO(authInfo);
    authInfo.pbNonce = (PUCHAR)iv;
    authInfo.cbNonce = ivLength;
    authInfo.pbTag = (PUCHAR)authTag;
    authInfo.cbTag = authTagLength;
    authInfo.pbAuthData = (PUCHAR)aad;
    authInfo.cbAuthData = aadLength;

    status = BCryptDecrypt(keyHandle, (PUCHAR)encryptedData, encryptedDataLength, &authInfo, NULL, 0, decryptedData, decryptedDataLength, &bytesDone, 0);
    
    BCryptDestroyKey(keyHandle);
    BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(algHandle, 0);

    return status;
}
```

Comment: It should be possible. C is a turing-complete language, so theoretically it can do anything that a turing machine can do. Useful links: [FIPS 197, Advanced Encryption Standard (AES) | CSRC](https://csrc.nist.gov/pubs/fips/197/final), [The Galois/Counter Mode of Operation (GCM) - gcm-spec.pdf](https://csrc.nist.rip/groups/ST/toolkit/BCM/documents/proposedmodes/gcm/gcm-spec.pdf)

Comment: See [**How to chain BCryptEncrypt and BCryptDecrypt calls using AES in GCM mode?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720414/how-to-chain-bcryptencrypt-and-bcryptdecrypt-calls-using-aes-in-gcm-mode)

Comment: Thank You for the suggestion @AndrewHenle, but didn't manage to get it to work, but added code sample of my attempt to the question.

Comment: .NET also has [built-in support for AES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aes?view=net-8.0). See [Cross-Platform Cryptography in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/cross-platform-cryptography), [C# with AES256 and SHA512 file encryption/decrption](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72162320/995714)

Comment: @exomm You need to read Microsoft's documentation for the `Bcrypt*()` functions *carefully*.  Unlike other libraries like OpenSSL, Microsoft's crypto implementations only provide the raw crypto engine - you have to do all the plumbing yourself: providing working buffers for AES/GCM's GHASH (all of 16 bytes - c'mon Microsoft! ), do the chunking for AAD and plaintext/ciphertext to block boundaries yourself, padding the final AAD and plaintext/ciphertext out to a block boundary, playing with bit values to compute/compare the AEAD tag.  It's not hard, but it's tedious.

Comment: In your example, the authentication tag is missing. It is possible that ciphertext and tag were concatenated during encryption, which means that both must be separated for `BCryptDecrypt` decryption (the tag usually comprises the last 16 bytes). In addition, the correct initialization of the `authInfo` with `BCRYPT_INIT_AUTH_MODE_INFO(authInfo)` (instead of `memeset(...)`) is missing.

Comment: Also your data is not OK. The tag size must be specified as 16 bytes (in your code 0 because of the above bug). But also the ciphertext size seems to be wrong with 12 bytes. I would recommend you to post *complete* sample data: plaintext, key, nonce, ciphertext and tag (concatenated or separated), so that their consistency can be verified! With these changes and my own data, your code works for me.

Comment: @Topaco Thank you for the answer. I was trying to look trough the Python code once again how it works, and seems like they take the iv with ciphertext[3:15](12 bytes) from the ciphertext and same with the encrypted data ciphertext[15:-16](12 bytes), but I do not see them using the last 16 bytes for anything. So the last 16 bytes is the auth tag correct? Added the last 16 bytes to the auth tag

Comment: If it doesn't work, either the encryption code is not compatible or your data is the problem (wrong format, corrupted etc.). So, post complete (non-productive) test data or the Python code. Otherwise this question can hardly be answered.

Comment: @Topaco I did the changes, it works, but the output data length is incorrect. Also could you create a answer so I can mark it as the solution : )

Comment: Your data does not have a terminating 0. Either you add this, or you apply an output function that in addition to the data is also given the data length over which the output is to take place. The length of the decrypted data equals that of the ciphertext, since GCM does not use padding.

Comment: @Topaco Thank you, seems to be working, do you want to write a answer?